# calculate max length of each field in csv file using groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

How can I print out the max length of each field in CSV file?

Example input:

```
foo,bar
abcd,12345
def,234567
```

Expected output:

```
Max length of fields: [4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code will do the job:

```
def txt='''foo,bar
abcd,12345
def,234567'''

txt.split('\n').collect { it.split(',') }.transpose().collect { field -> field.max { it.size() } }*.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used this:

```
def csv = new File('./myfile.csv').text

def max = [ ] as ArrayList

csv.eachLine { line, count ->

    def params = line.split(',')

    // skip the header line
    if (count > 0) 
    {
        params.eachWithIndex() { p, index ->        
            if (p.length() > max[index] ) {
                max[index] = p.length()
            }
        }
     }
}
println "Max length of fields: ${max}"
```

Comment: you can use `splitEachLine` instead of `eachLine` and later `split`